# specify directory path in javascript confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the app.js I have

```
app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads'}))
```

what's `'./uploads'` here? it's the same level with app.js, what's the different between `./uploads` with just `uploads`?

And I also saw some do `'_/upload'`, what's the different with 'upload' then?

Comment: See `multer` readme: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125522/path-syntax-rules

Comment: @MyrneStol that just doesn't mean anything to my question

Comment: Alice, the readme of multer shows what the meaning of the `dest` option is. The second shows in-and-outs of file paths on unix systems. Both resources are relevant, but not a direct answer to your question. Hence, I posted the links as comments.

Answer (score 1):

`./` means current directory which is the directory the program is being run from so `./uploads` and `uploads` are basically the same, `_/uploads` is a directory path with a parent directory i guess named `_` and a child directory named `uploads`.

Comment: uh? if the directory is named _ why not it's `/_uploads`?

Comment: it's the parent directory that is named `_` that is why there is `/` in the name to indicate a path that consists of a parent directory named `_` and a child directory named `uploads` and if you are on unix/linux `/_uploads` means a directory or file named `_uploads` in root.